# Joining table on JSON object

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have table A which has JSON column `f` with following content:

```
[{"name": "abc", "id": "1"}, {"name": "abcd", "id": "2"}, {"name": "abcde", "id": "3"} ]
```

I would like to join another table B on `id` inside JSON object described above but also take property `name` from JSON object.

I managed to create following query:

```sql
WITH sample_data_array(arr) AS (
   SELECT f FROM A
), sample_data_elements(elem) AS (
   SELECT json_array_elements(arr) FROM sample_data_array
)
SELECT CAST(elem->>'id' AS int) AS id, elem->'name' AS name FROM sample_data_elements
```

which returns following result:

```
id, name
1, "abc"
2, "abcd"
3, "abcde"
```

Sample data from table B:

```
id, title, slug  
1, "title 1", "title-1"
2, "title 2", "title-2"
3, "title 3", "title-3"
```

How do I join this result with table B and add more data (columns) from said table?

Expected result:

```
id, name, title, slug
1, "abc", "title 1", "title-1"
2, "abcd", "title 2", "title-2"
3, "abcde", "title 3", "title-3"
```

Comment: Please provide sample data from `tableB`, along with the expected result.

Comment: Sorry, forgot about that. I've edited my initial post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Click: demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e808827c26a11b2ec5cabd14171f8025)

```
SELECT
    b.id,
    elems ->> 'name' as name,           -- 3
    b.title
FROM
    a,
    json_array_elements(f) as elems     -- 1
JOIN
    b ON b.id = (elems ->> 'id')::int   -- 2
```

1. Get the elements out of the json array with `json_array_elements()`
2. Now you can join on the JSON attributes (in this case: The the `id` attribut as `text` and cast it into an `int` value)
3. After joining take all relevant values from `b` and the array elements (like the `name`)

Comment: I must admit I'm ashamed of my incompetence. Thank you for the explanation and correct (and also simple) solution.

Comment: We're all here to learn from each other :) No reason to be ashamed!